Performing a PCA on data of different hierarchical levels
I (novice) plan to use a PCA on several different, related, i.e. non-orthogonal questionnaire measures. These measures have composite scores (item sums etc.) and some of them have sub-facets. Also, some single-item variables might be more relevant for my research question than composite scores. Therefore, I would like to enter into the PCA item-level data, ideally, to not lose information. Can I enter composite measures (questionnaire/facet-level) and item level measures into that same PCA, i.e., different hierarchical levels of the data?
Also, how can I trace back which of the entered variables the resulting principal components are composed of, i.e., how much variance they contributed to the respective component? Is this the same as just looking at the factor loadings for each variable?
Is there some clustering approach I could use to further my understanding of which patterns exist in my data?
Help would be much appreciated!

You have indicated that an important reason for your conduct of dimension reduction is distinguishing the relative contributions of different items.  This effort will be at odds with the practice of basing the analysis on composite scores.
In addition, as you will find in many threads on this site, you will obtain more accurate (less inflated and more valid) results by using exploratory factor analysis instead of principal component analysis.  The former will take into account the subjective nature of your data and its degree of measurement error.  Also, you didn't mention rotation, but oblique rotation will allow for what are probably nontrivial degrees of correlation between the factors underlying your questionnaire responses.
There are other methods of reducing dimensions (in your words, "clustering" items).  Multidimensional scaling is worth a look.
